# recursive -1 for all models cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to set recursive -1 for all models, so I will not have to do it with every find request for each model.

I tried to do it from AppModel, like

```
function beforeFind($queryData) {
    $queryData['recursive'] = -1;
    return $queryData;
}
```

but it does not work, it gives an error, if I want to find some associative model with Containable - it can not find any field of the associated model - like

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'AssociatedModel.id' in 'field list'
```

Is there some way to handle this ?  I use cake 2.3.1

Thanks

Comment: "but it does not work, it gives an error" Does not help the people trying to help you. Put the actual error in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `AppModel` set `public $recursive = -1;` as a class var to set it for all models.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Will accept in 6 minutes (system does not allow sooner)